# Merging 2 div content on drag and drop of div on one another using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag

I need a jquery code for following scenario.
there are 4 div's, any one can be dragged and dropped on other.
while dropping the content of DIV1 and DIV2 should get merged.

Merged content also can be pulled out from and put back to origial div
my code is some thing like this.

```
<div id ="f1">
 <p id="c1">content 1</p>
</div>
<div id ="f2">
 <p id="c2">content 2</p>
</div>
<div id ="f3">
 <p id="c3">content 3</p>
</div>
<div id ="f4">
 <p id="c4">content 4</p>
</div>
```

if i drag f2 on f1 then in f1 i should find both c1 and c2 like this

```
<div id ="f1">  
 <p id="c1">content 1</p> 
 <p id="c2">content 2</p> 
</div>
<div id ="f3">
  <p id="c3">content 3</p>
</div>
<div id ="f4">
  <p id="c4">content 4</p>
</div>
```

now i should able to pull out c2 and put it any other div also. like this..

```
<div id ="f1">  
 <p id="c1">content 1</p> 
</div>
<div id ="f3">
  <p id="c3">content 3</p>
</div>
<div id ="f4">
  <p id="c4">content 4</p>
  <p id="c2">content 2</p> 
</div>
```

Please help me out. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to write some code for this. On the browser console I could see the

tags getting dragged around but on the UI itself the effect was not crystal clear.

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    $('#'+ev.target.id).parent().append($('#'+data));
}
</script>

<div id ="f1">
 <p id="c1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">content 1</p>
</div>
<div id ="f2">
 <p id="c2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">content 2</p>
</div>
<div id ="f3">
 <p id="c3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">content 3</p>
</div>
<div id ="f4">
 <p id="c4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">content 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hi Nikhil, I need not sort it, i need to merge it

Comment: This does not do any sorting. It is indeed merging the two 'p' tags inside the div tag. Its not very clear from the UI though so you can check the browser console in Chrome. Also if you remove .parent() in the drop() method, you will see 'content1 content2' coming up in the same line

Comment: Thank you very much, need little more help, while dragging out can i destroy empty div? also while dropping if no div exists can i create one?